# Nlog file target - cache log and only write to file when choose to

Tags: logging, .net-4.0, nlog

I've written a .net application to process some files periodically and I'm using nlog 2.0 file target to log to file. The application is called every 5 minutes, but actual processing only happen when there's file to be process. I would like to cache the log and only decide towards the end of the application to decide if the log is useful and then write to file. Is there any build in config and method I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have just commited a [ManualFlushTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog-Contrib/tree/master/NLog.ManualFlush) to [NLog Contrib](https://github.com/NLog/NLog-Contrib).

Currently it won't allow you to clear the queued log entries, but it will allow you to control when and if the target is flushed. It could easily be adapted to allowing you to clear the queue when needed.

Comment: Thanks, the code looks really simple, did you wrote this just for this question?

Comment: It has been at a very early stage for a while, so this question was what trigged the completion

Comment: Thanks, tested and it works. I'm calling an additional method `((ManualFlushWrapper)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("manualflush_wrapper")).EmptyLogs();` to clear the logs